# How to connect to the remote computer using PSexec connection in Python script

Tags: python-3.x

```
import subprocess,time

psexecloc ="C:\\Users\\administrator\\Desktop\\sample\\bin\\psexec.exe"
remotecmd="notepad.exe"
username = "XXXr"
password = "XXXXXXX"
remotehostname = "XXXXXXXX"
args = 
[psexecloc, "-u", username, "-p", password, remotehostname,   remotecmd]

output = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(30)
outstr=output.communicate()
stdoutstr = outstr[0]
stderrstr = outstr[1]
print ("Output Tupple: ",outstr)
```

**Just a cmd will popup for a ms, facing issue in this code please help**

Comment: I think you cannot execute graphical applications using `psexec`. Have you tried `cmd /c dir` for instance?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You can execute GUI with psexec. And does your remotehostname contains a `\\\` (double backslash) as a prefix? it should

Comment: `psexec \\ps-name notepad.exe`

Comment: In place of remotehostname, I am providing system IP.

Comment: aah good lead. Can you print `psexecloc` from python? you need raw prefix or 4 antislashes else it fails.

Comment: Seems like this is the issue.. I am not able to print psexecloc [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified..  How should I pass the path than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the syntax of [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) for your needs is:
`psexec \\hostname -u user -p pass executable` and if it's a GUI, add the `-i` flag.

*From [san](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7592895/san)'s comment, it takes more time for the GUI executable to load, than a non-gui exe*

So the following does work now that I've tested it:
The part that was missing is the backslashes before the hostname

```
import subprocess,time

psexecloc ="psexec.exe"
remotecmd="notepad.exe"
username = "XXXr"
password = "XXXXXXX"
remotehostname = "\\\\my-pc-name"
args = [psexecloc, "-i", "-u", username, "-p", password, remotehostname,   remotecmd]

output = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(30)
outstr=output.communicate()
stdoutstr = outstr[0]
stderrstr = outstr[1]
print ("Output Tuple: ",outstr)
```

Comment: Psexec is not invoking the notepad.exe in the target machine, but I could see Psexec process in the task manager..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any accessible remote to test it again at the moment. Have you checked after running psexec if notepad is running on the remote? (even if not visible). You could also open notepad from a simple batch file. You can mark psexec to copy the file and then execute it. Maybe it will behave different

Comment: no, notepad is not running in the target machine but I could see only psexec process running in the target machine.

Comment: Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: please try to add an [`-i flag`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec) (it receives a session number)

Comment: it's the session id of the user whom you want to open the gui app on his desktop

Comment: I have  tried by adding -i flag, still I am facing same problem, that I could only see only the process running in the task manager but not the interactive window in target machine(VM machine)

Comment: Thanks!. Works perfectly fine, only problem is taking more time to launch interactive window in remote machine:)..

Comment: Awesome, I've updated the answer so it'll be more complete